# Rearranging conditionally convergent series without changing the limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

Let $\{a_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that the series $\sum a_n$ is conditionally convergent, i.e. the limit $\lim\limits_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^Na_n =:L \in \mathbb{R}$ exists but $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \vert a_n \vert = \infty $.

Now by the Riemann rearrangement theorem for every $r \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a permutation $\sigma \in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{N})$ such that $\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^N a_{\sigma(n)} = r$. Lets write $S(\sigma) = r$ in this situation.

My (very vague) question is the following:

Is there a method to determine the subset of all permutations $\sigma \in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{N})$ such that $S(\sigma) = L$ (= the original limit of the series). Of course this contains all permutations which only permute a finite subset of the natural numbers, but I am mostly interested in how the sequence $\{a_n\}$ shapes this set.

EDIT: As pointed out by Martin in the comments, [there is an answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/213046/rearrangements-that-never-change-the-value-of-a-sum) for the subset of permutations that fix the original limit *for all* sequences.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/q/213046/116247 on MO.

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't get how I didn't find this post..